# Create an efficient logging library for logging socket communication

Tags: c#, concurrency, socket.io, load

I want to create a logging library that will log the packet send and receive b/w the multiple client and server application, I want to create this library optimize enough to record as many logs as it can but to achieve it it must overcome the IO bound issue for which I thought timer will be good, that for particular amount of time we are unable to log, then logging thread will be killed and we continue to work on without logging and when we received it again we should we this again. I want to know is there some better approach than that I can go with ? or someone one might have some opinion on this?

Comment: and i am using C# language making this library .

Comment: Just place your logs in a queue and have one worker thread process the items in the queue and log each item.

Comment: in my scenario there are 1 lac client each of them creating 4000 msg per second. don't you think that queue will be an overhead

Comment: It is, but it depends on if you are ok with not logging every message.

Comment: yes i am okay with loss of some logs when there is a lot of IO bound work, but the communication should not be compromised because of logging.

Comment: Ok. More power to you.

Comment: thanks for your idea it really going to help me i create the limited size buffer if buffer gets full then logs will lost otherwise it works fine

Answer (score 0):

when you have such huge amounts of logs, Elastic logging comes to picture. Elastic logging where you can log huge amount of data TB in seconds without any draw backs or system failures plus how to extract results from this huge amount of data. To use elastic logging you can use

https://www.elastic.co/solutions/logging

It Supports all cloud features as Auto-Scaling.  So no IO issues you will face.

Another Way as mentioned above is Messaging Queues like RabbitMQ which supports clustering.

Comment: this is great but i am not allowed to use any third party library that's the reason we are not even using log4net, I have to create my own . i think i can use the messages queue with limited size if the queue gets full the logs gets lost .

Comment: You can create sperate server for logging. And you call a service which is 1 way ' Fire and Forget ' and this server will have the whole load of IO and faults handling. So as like this no over work on ur main business servers